# Change format datetime in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How could I transform a date with typescript for example: Wed Aug 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 to 2021-08-07
But I want it to be in datetime format. string doesn't work for me.
I hope someone knows how to help me yes I would appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getFullYear`, `getMonth` and `getDate` method to get the desired output.

```js
var tmp = "Wed Aug 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300";
var dateObj = new Date(tmp);
var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
var month = (dateObj.getMonth()+1 > 9) ? dateObj.getMonth()+1 : "0"+(dateObj.getMonth()+1);
var date = (dateObj.getDate() > 9) ? dateObj.getDate() : "0"+dateObj.getMonth();

console.log(year + "-" + month + "-" + date);
```